# Python Pandas : How to skip columns when reading a file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have table formatted as follow :

```
foo - bar - 10 2e-5 0.0 some information
quz - baz - 4 1e-2 1 some other description in here
```

When I open it with pandas doing :

```
a = pd.read_table("file", header=None, sep=" ")
```

It tells me :

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 2, saw 12
```

What I'd basically like to have is something similar to the skiprows option which would allow me to do something like :

```
a = pd.read_table("file", header=None, sep=" ", skipcolumns=[8:])
```

I'm aware that I could re-format this table with `awk`, but I'd like to known whether a Pandas solution exists or not.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to be able to use column names, see answer in duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677313/skip-specific-set-of-columns-when-reading-excel-frame-pandas/56252452#56252452

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `usecols` parameter allows you to select which columns to use:

```
a = pd.read_table("file", header=None, sep=" ", usecols=range(8))
```

However, to accept irregular column counts you need to also use `engine='python'`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work the error still persists, the issue here is to coerce the parser to only use the desired columns without raising an error due to incorrect formatting

Comment: @EdChum, ah, ok, in that case this is probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python?rq=1

Comment: @otus yes changing the engine to python from the default works, you should post that as an edit

Comment: Do you manage to make it work with `engine="python"`? It's work without `usecols`, but then, the DataFrame is weird

Comment: And isn't python engine slower than the C one ? My files are somehow big.

Comment: @jeanrjc yes I believe that the python engine is slower so you have to make a choice between ease of use against speed with a little data wrangling here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux/OS X/Windows Cygwin, you should be able to prepare the file as follows:

```
cat your_file |  cut -d' ' -f1,2,3,4,5,6,7 > out.file
```

Then in Python:

```
a = pd.read_table("out.file", header=None, sep=" ")
```

**Example:**

Input:

```
foo - bar - 10 2e-5 0.0 some information
quz - baz - 4 1e-2 1 some other description in here
```

Output:

```
foo - bar - 10 2e-5 0.0
quz - baz - 4 1e-2 1
```

You can run this command manually on the command-line, or simply call it from within Python using the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).