# Pandas - read CSV into dataframe, where a column has a varying number of subcolumns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, is it possible to have a dataframe with a column that contains a varying number of subcolumns?

For example, suppose I have this CSV file:

```
transactionId, userName, date, itemList, totalCost
```

where the `itemList` contains a variable number of `itemId;itemPrice` pairs, with the pairs separated by a pipe (`|`). There is no upper bound on the number of `itemId;itemPrice` pairs in the list.

```
itemId ; itemPrice | itemId ; itemPrice
```

Here are some examples of rows:

```
transactionId, userName, date,       itemList,              totalCost
123,           Bob  ,    7/29/2017,  ABC;10|XYZ;20,         30
234,           Alice,    7/31/2017,  CDE;20|QRS;15|KLM;10,  45
```

The first row has two `itemId;itemPrice` pairs, while the second row has three pairs.

How can I create a dataframe to contain this information? Would I need a dataframe inside a dataframe?

There are other Stackoverflow posts on variable number of columns, but [they assume a maximum number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python).

Comment: You could consider storing them as dictionaries?

Comment: If you want  one separate value per cell (rather than a dictionary), you should decide whether to make the table "wide" (one extra column per extra value) or "tall" (one extra row per extra value). The answer would differ based on your choice.

Comment: @DYZ: I think I need them wide. For example, one of my goals is to audit whether the sum of the `itemPrice` values is equal to the `totalCost` of the entire row.

Answer (score 6):

I'd try to normalize your data [as proposed by @DYZ in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425597/pandas-read-csv-into-dataframe-where-a-column-has-a-varying-number-of-subcolu/45425758#comment77812738_45425597):

```
In [145]: df = df.join(df.pop('itemList')
     ...:                .str.extractall(r'(?P<item>\w+);(?P<price>\d+)')
     ...:                .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
     ...:

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
   transactionId userName       date  totalCost item price
0            123      Bob  7/29/2017         30  ABC    10
0            123      Bob  7/29/2017         30  XYZ    20
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017         45  CDE    20
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017         45  QRS    15
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017         45  KLM    10
```

Normalized data allows us to apply Pandas/Numpy/SciPy/etc. ufunctions directly on columns containing scalar values.

Demo: checking `totalCost`

```
df.price = pd.to_numeric(df.price, errors='coerce')

In [151]: df.assign(tot2=df.groupby(level=0).price.transform('sum'))
Out[151]:
   transactionId userName       date  totalCost item  price  tot2
0            123      Bob  7/29/2017         30  ABC     10    30
0            123      Bob  7/29/2017         30  XYZ     20    30
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017         45  CDE     20    45
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017         45  QRS     15    45
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017         45  KLM     10    45

In [152]: df.assign(tot2=df.groupby(level=0).price.transform('sum')).query("totalCost != tot2")
Out[152]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [transactionId, userName, date, totalCost, item, price, tot2]
Index: []
```

PS last empty DF shows that we don't have any entries where `totalCost != sum(price)`

Answer (score 2):

You parse them with a list comprehension

```
d1 = df.assign(
    itemList=[[x.split(';') for x in y.split('|')] for y in df.itemList.tolist()]
)

d1

   transactionId userName       date                           itemList  totalCost
0            123      Bob  7/29/2017             [[ABC, 10], [XYZ, 20]]         30
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017  [[CDE, 20], [QRS, 15], [KLM, 10]]         45
```

---

**Response to Comment**

```
f = lambda x: np.array(x)[:, 1].astype(int).sum()

d1.assign(sumPrice=d1.itemList.apply(f))

   transactionId userName       date                           itemList  totalCost  sumPrice
0            123      Bob  7/29/2017             [[ABC, 10], [XYZ, 20]]         30        30
1            234    Alice  7/31/2017  [[CDE, 20], [QRS, 15], [KLM, 10]]         45        45
```

Comment: This is an interesting representation. I created this dataframe, and `dataframe.info()` says that the `itemList` column is of type `Object`. How would I iterate over the items in `itemList` to sum up the `itemPrice` values?

Comment: I could do it but we have already gone down a dark path without a flashlight... You sure you want to keep going?  I'd stick to the tall dataframe in @MaxU's answer.

Comment: If you could, a lot of readers would appreciate it, myself included. I'm trying to understand the tradeoffs involved, e.g. space vs coding complexity.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 added example.

Comment: Thank you. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For completeness, this works as well: `d2 = d1.assign(itemPriceSum = d1.itemList.apply(lambda x: sum([int(item[1]) for item in x])))`