# pandas read_csv() for multiple delimiters

Tags: pandas

I have a file which has data as follows

```
1000000 183:0.6673;2:0.3535;359:0.304;363:0.1835
1000001 92:1.0
1000002 112:1.0
1000003 154435:0.746;30:0.3902;220:0.2803;238:0.2781;232:0.2717
1000004 118:1.0
1000005 157:0.484;25:0.4383;198:0.3033
1000006 277:0.7815;1980:0.4825;146:0.175
1000007 4069:0.6678;2557:0.6104;137:0.4261
1000009 2:1.0
```

I want to read the file to a pandas dataframe seperated by the multiple delimeters `\t, :, ;`

I tried

`df_user_key_word_org = pd.read_csv(filepath+"user_key_word.txt", sep='\t|:|;', header=None, engine='python')`

It gives me the following error.

`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error could be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.`

Why am I getting this error?

So I thought I'll try to use the regex string. But I am not sure how to write a split regex. r'\t|:|;' doesn't work.

What is the best way to read a file to a pandas data frame with multiple delimiters?

Comment: @jezrael When using a capture group, the pipes are not needed (the pipe in fact becomes a delimiter).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - good to know, thanks ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - btw, error means there is some problem in data I guess, so not this dupe, because dupe answer is same as OP use in this question :(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ do you mean to say the regex string should be r'\t:;' ? I tried it and it did not seperate by data at all.

`df_user_key_word_org = pd.read_csv(filepath+"user_key_word.txt", delimiter=r'\t:;', header=None, engine='python')`

Comment: No, it should be `r'[\t:;]'`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. However, I am still getting the `pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 29 fields in line 11, saw 45. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.` error. 

I checked the data column, and there are no trailing commas or anything. Do you have any suggestion to debug it other than setting `error_bad_lines=False` because I have it appearing in too many data points?

Comment: Did you try `quotechar='"'`?

Comment: Yes, it was set to the default value. I did not change it. Still, I see the error.@jezrael I added more data to the question. Do you see any errors in the data that could cause this ParserError?

Comment: "expected 29 fields in line 11, saw 45" is (I believe) not related to delimiter but rather that you have rows with variable number of columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Variable Number of Columns with Pandas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python)

Comment: @coldspeed  in playing around with this, it seems you do need some separator like `sep="\s+|;|:"` or else you need to put in brackets like `sep="[ ;:]"`. But just plain `sep=" ;:"` did not work for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From this question, [Handling Variable Number of Columns with Pandas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python), one workaround to  `pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 29 fields in line 11, saw 45.` is let `read_csv` know about how many columns in advance.

```
my_cols = [str(i) for i in range(45)] # create some col names
df_user_key_word_org = pd.read_csv(filepath+"user_key_word.txt",
                                   sep="\s+|;|:",
                                   names=my_cols, 
                                   header=None, 
                                   engine="python")
# I tested with s = StringIO(text_from_OP) on my computer
```

[image]

Hope this works.

Comment: I just did something similar which I won't post b/c this seems to work fine. ;-)

Comment: @JohnE I saw your comment right after I posted it :D

Comment: let read_csv know about how many rows in advance - but my_cols?? a little confusing, rows or cols?

Comment: @SunKe thanks for  catching that, it should be my_cols :)

Comment: I am a bit confused about why ‘my_cols’ has been defined. I think it is not being used in pd.read_csv() command.

Comment: @user408108 there is a `names` parameter in the function.