# How to read file delimited by space and :

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My data is of the form :

1 440:0.033906222568727 730:0.0424739279722748 1523:0.0773048148348295 1893:0.0433930684646909

1 271:0.0646290650479301 405:0.0653366028581683 584:0.0744087075001463 770:0.0717824200677465

1 577:0.0679078686536282 761:0.0506946081073312

-1 440:0.0437614564467411 798:0.0370070258333617 831:0.0549176430011721 1681:0.0715035548706038 1963:0.102891965918849 2667:0.0461603813033019 2899:0.0672807783934756

I want output in the form of a table:

```
1 440 0.033906222568727 ......
1 271 0.0646290650479301 ...... 
1 271 0.0646290650479301 ......
1 577 0.0679078686536282 .........
```

I have tried using

```
 x = pd.read_csv('rcv1_train.binary', sep = "\s+|:",  engine = 'python')
```

and got an error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 413 fields in line 134, saw 419. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: "_I have tried using_" - and what happened?

Comment: I got an error: pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 413 fields in line 134, saw 419. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Variable Number of Columns with Pandas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have bad data in line 134

try using `error_bad_lines=False` .

```
x = pd.read_csv('rcv1_train.binary', sep = "\s+|:",  engine = 'python', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: This is giving me all Nan values, and makes me skip almost half of the rows

Comment: That is because the data in the CSV is incorrect. rows with incorrect data will be filled with Nan vals

Comment: @Rakesh "If False, then these "bad lines" will [be] dropped from the DataFrame that is returned." The "bad" lines will _not_ be filled with Nans. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html