# Detecting CSV file truncation when NA is a valid value

Tags: python, pandas

If I use the Pandas read_csv() function, elements of short rows are mapped to NaN by default. I would like to suppress that mapping while interpreting `NA` as `NaN`. I'm mostly interested in file truncation as a result of transmission problems, but short rows in the middle of the file should feature the same `missing"` value. I tried messing around with `na_filter=False` and `keep_default_na=False`, and while each seemed to map empty cells to the empty string, neither mapped the string `NA` to `NaN`.

Is there a way to have my cake (`NA` => `NaN`) and eat it too (missing values not mapped to `NaN`)? (I'm using `Pandas 0.22.0 w/ Python 3.6.`)

Example:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,NA,4
4,5
12
```

Assume the file has been truncated, so the characters `"12"` are the last in the file (no EOF). With `na_filter` and `keep_default_na` at their default values of `True`, the resulting values are

```
1,2,NaN,4
4,5,NaN,NaN
12,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

If I set either to `False`, I get

```
1,2,NA,4
4,5,,
12,,,
```

I would like to find some way to get a `NaN` out of the third column of the first row without also mapping the missing values to `NaN`.

Comment: You need to give more details, e.g., example data, expected output, attempts at a solution **not** in paragraph form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Pandas will interpret the following values as `NaN` (from the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values)):

> The default `NaN` recognized values are `['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND',
>   '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A N/A', '#N/A', 'N/A', 'n/a', 'NA', '#NA', 'NULL',
>   'null', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan', '']`.

In order to avoid `NA` being parsed as a null value, you need to set `keep_default_na=False` and specify the `na_values` directly.

To address your second problem, in order to avoid Pandas throwing errors when reading in a file with a variable number of columns, you need to specify the columns names. Putting it all together:

```
# new null values, removing NA from the list
new_na_values = ['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A N/A', '#N/A', 'N/A', 'n/a', '#NA', 'NULL', 'null', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan', '']

# read in the file
df = pd.read_csv("<path to file>.csv", keep_default_na=False, na_values=new_na_values, names=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])
```

EDIT: It looks like the most recent version of Pandas can now read in files with a variable number of columns without explicitly setting the column names (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python), for example). So, depending on your version of Pandas, you may not need the `names` argument.

Comment: Thanks. Setting na_values did what I needed. Wasn't aware I had a second problem. Pandas hasn't raised any exceptions.

Comment: Yep, just updated my `pandas` version and now it reads files with variable number of columns fine--glad they fixed this. Updated the answer