# How to Read A CSV With A Variable Number of Columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My csv file looks like this:

```
5783,145v
g656,4589,3243,tt56
6579
```

How do I read this with pandas (or otherwise)?

(the table should contain empty cells)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling Variable Number of Columns with Pandas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a dummy separator, and then use [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) (by `","`) with `expand=True`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', sep=" ", header=None)
df = df[0].str.split(",", expand=True).fillna("")
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      0     1     2     3
0  5783  145v            
1  g656  4589  3243  tt56
2  6579
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the solution proposed by @researchnewbie is good. If you need to replace the NaN values for say, zero, you could add this line after the read:

```
dataFrame.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You can also do dataFrame.replace(NaN, 0). The first argument being what you want to replace in the entire dataFrame and the second what you want to replace it with. If they want an empty string, 0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Your empty cells should contain the NaN value, which essentially null.