# Reading CSV file with different length

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read data from a tsv-file, but the format of the file is on the form

```
nm0007219   Donald Cook tt0042819
nm0457839   John Kitzmiller tt0045018   tt0042692
nm0777743   Karl Schwetter  tt0043483   tt0049422   tt0044322   tt0047989
```

I get the error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 2, saw 5
> My current code looks like this

```
TSV_file = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)
```

Ultimately my goal is to find the amount of edges in the dataset

Comment: What is your expected dataframe after `read_csv`

Comment: what defines what an edge is in your dataset? My initial thought here is that a tabular data structure like a dataframe is not what you should be using. You probably should be reading the file line by line using the csv module to build some kind of adjacency list.

Answer (score 2):

You could define column headings as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df_tsv = pd.read_csv('input.tsv', sep='\t', header=None, names=['nm', 'Name', *(f'tt{i:02}' for i in range(1, 6))])
print(df_tsv)
```

This would give you a dataframe as:

```
          nm             Name       tt01       tt02       tt03       tt04  tt05
0  nm0007219      Donald Cook  tt0042819        NaN        NaN        NaN   NaN
1  nm0457839  John Kitzmiller  tt0045018  tt0042692        NaN        NaN   NaN
2  nm0777743   Karl Schwetter  tt0043483  tt0049422  tt0044322  tt0047989   NaN
```

You can either set the range to the required largest possible number of `tt....` entries per row. Or set it to a large number and then remove all columns that are empty:

```
df_tsv = df_tsv.dropna(axis=1, how='all')   # remove empty columns
```

Comment: This looks like it would work but requires the user to know the maximum number of columns to expect. The comments on [this answer about handling a variable number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252012/5906389) give a technique to read each line in the file to find the max columns: `num_cols = max(len(line.split(',')) for line in f)` where `f` is the file. It does require reading the file twice.

Comment: I am guessing it would be much quicker to just overestimate the number of columns and discard them later using pandas rather than reading a file twice. Probably ok for small files though.